# Como transicionar para o fragment anterior ao pressionar o botão voltar?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Estou tendo o seguinte problema: Tenho uma activity, na qual chamo uma fragment da seguinte forma:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment frag = new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_container, frag);
    ft.commit();
```

A partir dessa fragment que é chamada, existe um botão que cria uma outra fragment, que eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    Fragment fragment = new MyOtherFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Acontece que quando eu aperto o botão físico "voltar" a partir dessa última fragment, o aplicativo fecha, sem dar nenhuma mensagem de erro. Sei que é possível voltar pra fragment anterior simplesmente mudando a função do botão físico "voltar", mas diante desse problema eu imaginei que poderia haver uma outra forma de se fazer isso. Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Veja se [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14275833/4319922) ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
Fragment fragment = new MyOtherFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
ft.commit();
```

O comando `ft.addToBackStack("pilha");` adiciona esse fragment a pilha, a tag que usei "pilha" pode ser qualquer coisa. Depois disso ao clicar em voltar ele voltará para o fragment anterior e quando estiver no último, irá fechar o app como está ocorrendo agora